# Scrapy: No module named test_1.items

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

Im trying from import items from the .items file with `from test_1.items import Items` i keep getting the "No module named test_1.items" error. My structure is

```
test_1/
test_1/test_2/
test_1/scrapy.cfg

test_1/test_2/spiders/
test_1/test_2/ __init__.py
test_1/test_2/items.py
test_1/test_2/pipelines.py
test_1/test_2/settings.py

test_1/test_2/spiders/ __init__.py
test_1/test_2/spiders/today_spider.py
```

im coding in today_spider after i modify the items.py file and get`ImportError: No module named...` this error. As you see i tried to change the manes not to be identical. i also tryied to start today_spider with `__future__ import absolute_import`. any advise?

thks a lot for your time

Comment: `from test_2.items import Items`? What's in your `items.py` ?

Comment: "from scrapy.item import Item, Field                                class TestItem(Item):                                                        
    name = Field()
    price = Field()" i dont get how to format the comment....its the staff between "" structured ok